# How to label third gender "diverse" in registration forms?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammatical-gender

We are introducing a third-gender option in a couple of registration forms and I wonder how to label the checkbox in English. By now, it is common to use "männlich/weiblich/**divers**" in German job advertisements. The word *diverse* exists in English as well, but I'm unsure whether it is commonly used to refer to a person that identifies as third-gender.

Would "male/female/**diverse**" be a proper translation?

I have researched with Google, but most articles introduce a vast number of additional options that inter-people might want to be referred to. The requirement in our forms, however, is to have only three options. Internationally it seems uncommon to name genders in a job advertisement at all.

**Example:**

[x] male, [ ] female, [ ] diverse

I have also considered using "male/female/**other**".

Comment: I'm seeing more *nonbinary* listed, plus "I do not wish to answer." The fixation on having not two but three labels can be one's undoing, by labeling the unlabelable.

Comment: I think the correct translation of the German _divers_ would be 'other' not 'diverse'.

Comment: 'Withheld' or 'unspecified' are more felicitous translations ('diverse' here being inappropriate).

Comment: "Other" is common in English-language forms. It is normally accompanied by a free-text entry field to submit the "other" option. This may or may not be convenient from a statistics perspective, but is by far the best way to give the user the most agency to describe themself as they prefer (including in other fields such as ethnicity/race). Also, "I prefer not to say" is *not* the same thing as "other."

Comment: "Other" plus a space/box/text field (for the user to enter their preferred gender designation) is another common way of doing it.

Comment: In English they do it by asking what your pronouns are. Only 3rd person pronouns are allowed, but _they/their/them_ is the equivalent of _divers_.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/asktransgender/comments/lmkco1/is_gender_other_in_a_web_form_offensive/